# Confusing Clojure Compile Errors -- Bad line reporting?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, noir

I am getting compile errors while running `lein run` on my [Noir](http://webnoir.org/) project. It was working, and then suddenly it stopped working. My suspicion was that the error is connected with trying to include `[org.pegdown/pegdown "1.1.0"]` in my dependencies vector in the project file, but I don't know for sure. I removed that line, ran `lein clean; lein deps` and then tried `lein run` again, but the error persists.

Below are two separate errors that I get. I don't know what triggers either error. All my files (in the namespace "benekastah") report an error at line 1, which is typically a normal `ns` call.

The second error seems to indicate that the problem is in post_modify.clj, but that was working before and I haven't changed it.

I tried the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233334/exceptionininitializererror-when-using-leiningen) and it didn't seem to work.

Any insight into these confusing errors?

Error 1:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:165)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6476)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6902)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:357)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:348)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:427)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5352)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at user$eval1.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6454)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6431)
at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2795)
at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:296)
at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:315)
at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:348)
at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:426)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:405)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:518)
at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2030)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:417)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:604)
at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5363)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512)
at benekastah.views.common$loading__4505__auto__.invoke(common.clj:1)
at benekastah.views.common__init.load(Unknown Source)
at benekastah.views.common__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2030)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:417)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5352)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512)
at benekastah.views.blog.index$loading__4505__auto__.invoke(index.clj:1)
at benekastah.views.blog.index__init.load(Unknown Source)
at benekastah.views.blog.index__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2030)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:417)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5352)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at noir.server$load_views.doInvoke(server.clj:25)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at benekastah.server$eval10.invoke(server.clj:5)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at clojure.core$refer.doInvoke(core.clj:3775)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5252)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:604)
at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5363)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at benekastah.css.base__init.load(Unknown Source)
at benekastah.css.base__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
... 92 more
```

Error 2:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException, compiling:(post_modify.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3342)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:6985)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:6975)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7046)
at clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:385)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:425)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5352)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at noir.server$load_views.doInvoke(server.clj:25)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3337)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:6985)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7046)
at clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:385)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:425)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
at clojure.core$compile$fn__4615.invoke(core.clj:5397)
at clojure.core$compile.invoke(core.clj:5396)
at user$eval27.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6455)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6431)
at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2795)
at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:296)
at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:315)
at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:348)
at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:426)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:405)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:518)
at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at clojure.lang.Compiler$ObjExpr.emitVar(Compiler.java:4728)
at clojure.lang.Compiler$DefExpr.emit(Compiler.java:395)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:6984)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7046)
at clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:385)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:425)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5352)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:551)
at benekastah.views.blog.post_modify$loading__4505__auto__.invoke(post_modify.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3337)
... 46 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:165)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6476)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6902)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:357)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:348)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:427)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5352)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at user$eval1.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6454)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6431)
at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2795)
at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:296)
at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:315)
at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:348)
at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:426)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:405)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:518)
at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2030)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:417)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:604)
at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5363)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512)
at benekastah.views.common$loading__4505__auto__.invoke(common.clj:1)
at benekastah.views.common__init.load(Unknown Source)
at benekastah.views.common__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2030)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:417)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5352)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512)
at benekastah.views.blog.index$loading__4505__auto__.invoke(index.clj:1)
at benekastah.views.blog.index__init.load(Unknown Source)
at benekastah.views.blog.index__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2030)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:417)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5352)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at noir.server$load_views.doInvoke(server.clj:25)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at benekastah.server$eval10.invoke(server.clj:5)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at clojure.core$refer.doInvoke(core.clj:3775)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5252)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:604)
at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5363)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at benekastah.css.base__init.load(Unknown Source)
at benekastah.css.base__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
... 92 more
```

benekastah.views.blog.post_modify.clj

```
(ns benekastah.views.blog.post-modify
  (:require [noir.response :as resp]
            [somnium.congomongo :as congo]
            [clj-time.core :as time]
            [clj-time.format :as time-format]
            [clj-time.coerce :as time-coerce]
            [clojure.string :as cl-string]
            [benekastah.lib.string :as b-string])
  (:use noir.core
        benekastah.models.db))

(defn- save-post
  [post]
  (try (save! :post post)
       (resp/redirect "/")
    (catch Exception e
      {:status 500
       :body (str "Could not save post: " e)})))

(defpage [:post "/post"] [& param-lists]
         (let [params (populate-defaults 
                        :post 
                        (apply hash-map (apply concat param-lists)))
               {date :date, title :title } params
               slug (str 
                      (time-format/unparse 
                        (time-format/formatters :date)
                        (time-coerce/from-date date)) 
                      "_"
                      (cl-string/replace (cl-string/trim title)
                                         #"[^\w\-]"
                                         "_"))
               p (merge params {:slug slug})]
           (save-post p)))

(defpage [:put "/post"] {:keys [id]}
         (let [post (congo/fetch-by-id id)]
           (save-post post)))

(defpage [:delete "/post"] {:keys [id]}
         (let [post (congo/fetch-by-id id)]
           (congo/destroy! :post post)))
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but these sorts of issues are usually avoided if one takes advantage of the repl to incrementally construct their application, rather than writing a bunch of code then seeing if it all works.

Comment: Agreed. I do tend to develop that way, which makes me even more confused. The step after which the failure came was reversed, but the problem persists. I'm trying to retrace my steps, but without success. Is there a particular class of errors that this may be related to?

Comment: At the bottom of both stack traces is a NullPointerException when trying to refer something during the load of benekastah.css.base.  Might want to look there.  Also, 1.3.0 has prettier stack traces.

Comment: I have the same error on a program that works fine in the REPL via SLIME. When I finished working and went to package it up with "lein uberjar", I got the errors above. "lein run" also fails in the same way. I tried "lein clean", deleting ~/.lein, even upgrading to lein2-preview, to no effect. The app still works fine from the REPL, it just refuses to run any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I "fixed" my problem: In response to @Alex's comment suggesting I look at benekastah.css.base, I commented out the bulk of that file and restarted the server. At this point, the error message pointed to benekastah.css.blog, where I commented out the bulk of the file again. Then the error message pointed to benekastah.css.theme (the last file in the benekastah.css.* group), at which point I took the same steps as with the other two files. Then the server worked. So, working backwords, I uncommented the code in each file, and everything seems to be running fine again. I also was able to add the dependency back in to pegdown. Weird.

If anyone has any insight to the way that clojure, leiningen or java works that would result in any of this making sense, I would be interested to hear it.

For the record, I am using cssgen for my benekastah.css.* files. It seems to be working fine for the most part.

Answer (score 16):

This is caused when a function in a namespace replaces a core function, like `get`. You can find some discussion of it on the clojure-dev mailing list [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/clojure-dev/UbD96_SKb7E/akVnOs1qZlIJ). The solution, rather than renaming your functions is to place `(:refer-clojure :exclude [name-of-replaced-function])` in your `ns` form.

Comment: Looks like this is meant to be a comment to @Nutritioustim. +1, though. I've been wondering about this for a while.

Comment: Aaaand this just solved a really confusing problem for me. Thanks again!

Comment: Dave's answer helps me out of the problem!

Comment: This is the better solution. I'll use this in future. Thanks.

Comment: Although, I had a little different line numbers in the stacktrace (apparently because of having another version of the tool), this was the solution for my case!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, and I actually got to the root of it. Turns out that I had my own get and remove function definitions in my code. This was somehow interfering with clojure.core's get and remove function definitions in that namespace. Those NPE (on compilation) were the result. To fix the problem, all I did was rename my function definitions to getk and removek.

HTH

Comment: Using silly names like `getk` defeats the whole point of namespaces :) resorting to `refer-clojure` instead is the clean solution.