# lein repl zip file is empty exception

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I get the error messages when I enter `lein repl` in my project root folder. I have tried to delete the .lein directory in home folder and redownload lein but it doesn't work for me.

possible duplicate:
[ExceptionInInitializerError when using leiningen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233334/exceptionininitializererror-when-using-leiningen)

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:153)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:117)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeConstructor(Reflector.java:180)
at leiningen.core.classpath$extract_native_deps.invoke(classpath.clj:43)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:167)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617)
at leiningen.core.classpath$when_stale.doInvoke(classpath.clj:66)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:580)
at leiningen.core.classpath$resolve_dependencies.doInvoke(classpath.clj:231)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
at leiningen.core.eval$prep.invoke(eval.clj:54)
at leiningen.core.eval$eval_in_project.invoke(eval.clj:282)
at leiningen.repl$start_server.invoke(repl.clj:117)
at leiningen.repl$server$fn__6110.invoke(repl.clj:173)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617)
at clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.doInvoke(core.clj:1788)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:621)
at clojure.core$bound_fn_STAR_$fn__4102.doInvoke(core.clj:1810)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Edit:
I'm running leiningen 2.1.2 on ubuntu 12.10 64bit machine.

Note: If I run `lein repl` outside my project root folder, it is fine.

Comment: When you say downloading `lein` again, do you mean you get exactly the same error?

Comment: are you using lein 1 or 2?

Comment: @JohnJ: Yes, the same error exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have once successfully made that problem go away when using lein2 by running

```
lein clean
```

My next guess would be to move your ~/.m2/repository out of the way and try again.

Answer (score 1):

this is because you can't name your uberjar the same as the jar file named internally by leiningen.
just make sure you add something like "name-0.1.0-**STABLE**" or anything else like SNAPSHOT or LATEST to your :uberjar ... :uberjar-name.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing would work for me (cleaning, blowing away ~/.m2). I even went to another machine. Then I thought maybe `lein` is confused with seeing these two entries together:

```
:jar-name "my-server.jar"
:uberjar-name "my-server.jar"
```

So I commented out `:uberjar-name` and ran `lein jar` and it didn't give me the exception - ran through to the end.